# Nilpotent or just nil idempotent ideal?

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, artinian

Let $R$ be a ring with zero Krull dimension and $I$ be an idempotent ideal contained in the Jacobson radical $J(R)$ of $R$. Could one infer just with these hypotheses that $I$ is a *nilpotent* ideal?

I know that Krull dimension being zero implies that $J(R)$ is equal to the set of nilpotent elements of $R$ (whence a nil ideal), and also $R/J(R)$ is von-Neumann regular. So, I only  deduce that $I$ is a *nil* ideal.

Thanks for any hint or suggestion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This example](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1597200/121097) works also here. The only thing to show is $\dim R=0$, but this is obvious.

Comment: This local ring with a nil idempotent maximal ideal is one of my favorite examples.

Comment: @user26857 Why $\dim R=0$? I think we must show that $R$ has only one prime ideal. How?

Comment: If $X_1\in P$ and $X_2^2-X_1\in P$ then $X_2^2\in P$, so $X_2\in P$, and so on.

Comment: @user26857 And if $X_1$ does not belong to $P$....

Comment: @karparvar As far as I know, the prime ideals of a quotient ring $R/I$ have the form $P/I$ with $P\subset R$ prime *containing* $I$.